# Trying to make a search function that filters a column to rows containing an input in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a simple excel sheet with a searchable table. Right now the searching uses autofilter in vba to return results but this is limited to exact matches.

```
Sub bystudy()

Dim i As String

i = InputBox("What study?", "bystudy", "Study ID")

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FreezerMaster").Range.AutoFilter _
Field:=4, _
Criteria1:=i

End Sub
```

I tried recording a macro and filtering to contain but I don't know how to make it work with a variable.

```
Sub bystudy()

Dim i As String

i = InputBox("What study?", "bystudy", "Study ID")

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FreezerMaster").Range.AutoFilter _
Field:=4, _
Criteria1:="=*i*"

End Sub
```

above code just shows me rows where column 4 contains an i. lol.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Criteria1:="=*" & i & "*"`

Comment: Side note... use a more descriptive variable name than `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You were close!

Here is an example of including the variable:

```
Dim str_Search As String

str_Search = "is"

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & str_Search & "*"
```

Using this sample data set:

[image]

And after running the above code, I get:

[image]